# What is the expansion of this GNU C,C++ macro

Tags: c++, c, gnu

What these C macros get  expanded to ?

```
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define AHB2PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x08000000)
#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000)
#define GPIOB_BASE            (AHB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0400)

#define BLINK_GPIOx(_N) (GPIO_TypeDef *)(GPIO_BASE +(GPIOB_BASE-GPIOA_BASE)*(_N)))
#define BLINK_PORT_NUMBER(4)
```

the call to this is

```
 GPIO_SetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER), BLINK_PIN_MASK(8));
```

Comment: This is simple textual substitution, or am I missing some subtlety here?

Comment: You could pre-process the file and see what happens...

Comment: either typos or too many lines missing. you can try to run g++ INPUT_FILE | grep GPIO_SetBits

Comment: @lonewasp: `g++ INPUT_FILE` isn't going to write anything to standard output.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, you are right that should have been cpp INPUT_FILE (preprocessor only invocation)

Comment: @lonewasp: `g++ -E` is probably better. The compiler might use a different preprocessor executable and/or pass options to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-E` option of `gcc` compiler to see the preprocessor output.
example: `gcc -E program.c -o preprocessOutput.p` 
Then view the contents of the file `preprocessOutput.p`

Comment: Ah, i was about to correct my comment.

Comment: Cleaning up comments...